# Parsing Parameter though JQuery.load

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

I have got div in a page to load a jsp page (another.jsp) which takes the parameters value

```
$("#div").load('another.jsp?a=1&b=2');
```

After a number of tries with using different method, it is still not able to achieve the result as expected.

I have also tried using the following in the another.jsp, which still not possible to retrieve the parameters

```
(function($) {
    $.QueryString = (function(a) {
        if (a == "")
            return {};
        var b = {};
        for (var i = 0; i < a.length; ++i) {
            var p = a[i].split('=');
            if (p.length != 2)
                continue;
            b[p[0]] = decodeURIComponent(p[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
        }
        return b;
    })(window.location.search.substr(1).split('&'))
})(jQuery);
```

Would someone please give me some guidances?

Also, I have been trying

```
$("#div").load('another.jsp', {'a':1, 'b':2});
```

which doesn't work either

Comment: Read it here [jQuery.load()](http://api.jquery.com/load/)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of doing it is this way

```
$("#div").load('another.jsp', {a:'1', b:'2'});
```

The quotes come for the value and not for the field

Basically this is the syntax

```
$('#mydiv').load('newPage.jsp', {field1: 'value1', ...});
```